# Someone who constantly learns?

Tags: definition

I'm just trying to find a word that describes someone who's always in the process of learning. I'm talking more about a way of living than about someone like an apprentice etc. though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Lifelong learner" is the term widely used to describe a person who actively engages in learning new things as a lifestyle choice. There is the single word "philomath" - lover of learning - but it is rarely seen and would not be understandable to 99+% of even native English users.

Note that "philomath" was last seen in common usage as an honorific for almanac writers. [Poor Richard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poor_Richard%27s_Almanack) being the most famous and possibly the last.

Comment: +1 for "philomath". I've never heard that term before, but it's very cool. :-)

Comment: You're right on the money with that 99+%. If I've ever seen *philomath* before, I certainly don't recall it. I'd have guessed *lover of mathematics*, though, so it was reassuring to see OED defines it as *A lover of learning; a student or scholar, **esp. of mathematics**, natural philosophy, etc.*. But they also say it's "Now chiefly hist." I'm adding a link so OP and/or future visitors will realise it's not likely to be worth learning (unless they also take the trouble to remember *why* they probably don't want to use it! :)

Comment: Related to *polymath*, a somewhat more common word (but still somewhat unusual).